# MySQL Subquery With LIMIT vs JOIN

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, subquery, percona, xtradb

I would prefer to use a JOIN for this, but none of the solutions are either viable due to performance impacts or they don't return the right result set.

The `RunTime` column is a UNIX timestamp captured every night at midnight. Not every entry will occur every night, meaning an entry for *Entry1* may have occurred two days ago, but not today.

*Schema:*

```
 `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RunTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`),
```

*Example Desired Results:*

```
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| Name        | LastRunTime        | Count    |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| Random Name |     1339131600 |       73 |
| RandomName2 |     1337131600 |       13 |
... etc
```

Essentially, my working query looks like the below. It will query the table for yesterdays data.

```
select Name,
       RunTime AS LastRunTime,
       count(*) AS Count
from TABLE
where RunTime = 
    (
    select DISTINCT( RunTime ) from TABLE WHERE r.Name=Name order by RunTime LIMIT 1,1
    ) 
and Category in 
    (
    select AnotherTable .ID from AnotherTable where AnotherTable.Status = 1
    )

group by Name
```

The problem is, this query is slow. I want to move away from the first subquery, on the `RunTime` column, but the LIMIT and association is getting the best of me. The above takes a very, *very*, long time.

Does anyone have an example of a way to:

Get the second most recent `RunTime`, the count of rows for the second most recent `RunTime`, quickly and efficiently where `RunTime` is not consistent across all rows?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What do you indexes look like? What is result of running the query and the sub query with an `EXPLAIN` in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stuck with a subquery but changed the timeframe to `WHERE RunTime = (SELECT MAX(RunTime) - 86400...`.

All other solutions or attempts where either too demanding or convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Select Name, Max(RunTime ) as  LastRunTime        ,Count(*) as Count
    from TABLE a
    Inner join AnotherTable b ON a.Category =b.ID and   b.Status = 1
    GROUP BY name
    Having LastRunTime < Max(RunTime )
```

Comment: Why are you doing `MAX(RunTime)` twice? In your `Having` you could say `HAVING RunTime < LastRunTime`

Comment: @arnoudhgz, you need the `MAX()` as having should only be used with some sort of comparison function, otherwise you should just use a where.

Comment: now, with your last edit,  the query can't get results. You're now saying that only the result of something smaller than itself can be in the result..... (`LastRuntime` is the same `MAX(RunTime)`, so `LastRunTim < MAX(RunTime)` will give you 0 results)

Comment: @sixeightzero `LastRunTime` is not a table column. `HAVING RunTime < LastRunTime` should do the trick for this query

Comment: @arnoudhgz, i get column not found when using RunTime. If i pass LastRunTime, the having works, but it pulls ALL records that are not the current runtime.